# React Router - change url without navigation

Tags: react-router

I have a new product page with the url /product/0. When product is saved using a button, I want to show 'Saved Successfully' message and change url to /product/1024 without actually navigating to that page as this would cause GET requests for the product and other data on the page.

I tried the Navigation mixin, however both, the transitionTo and replaceWith actually cause componentWillReceiveProps and I can't figure out a way how to distinguish my case (when all data on the page is already relevant) from navigation between different products, when data has to be reloaded.

So basically I am looking for a way to just change the url with React Router.

Comment: I'm just learning about react myself, but it seems like you would want to perform the navigation and pull the saved data from a data store with the updated info returned from the save.

Comment: It goes back to the componentWillReceiveProps - there is nothing to distinguish save + navigate from just navigate. I can't figure out an if condition for when to go to the server and when to get data from the store.

Comment: Besides, I'd prefer to not even get into the componentWillReceiveProps, if possible - all data is already on the screen / store...

Comment: wondering if you found the answer for this, same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

In a SPA there's no navigating to another page, the history change could lead to a different route being rendered, but as per your example, the same route will be rendered, so the only thing that did happen is a `state` change of the props of the `Route` component.

So you need to check this state with the previous state in `componentWillReceiveProps` and see if you need to refetch the data.